# Hard start kit in old Traulsen commercial refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

The unit cycles with a buzzing noise for 1s every 30s or so - I presume the compressor is locked, or possibly the relay / capacitor is bad.

I was going to try a Supco 210 hard start kit - is that a reasonable thing to do ? As I understand it, that would replace both the capacitor and the relay. The choice of kit is affected by whether it has a run capacitor or just a start capacitor though, and Supco is not willing to tell me if I can't figure it out myself ;) Compressor is a Copeland RSN4-0050-IAA ... is there some way I can tell?

Comment: A bit far from the topic of Home Improvement unless you have one of these in your house..

Comment: @keshlam Which would be unusual but far from impossible, particularly if somebody wants the commercial "look" - one of these picked up used from a restaurant going out of business (or refurbed or whatever) is a **lot** cheaper than a new SubZero.

Comment: Before you buy something you may not need, get an accurate reading on AC voltage at the outlet while the compressor is trying and failing to start.

Comment: Well, it's a farmhouse, but yes, I do have one (actually two) here. And they're nearly 50 years old, but cost $200 for both ;) WRT voltage, it is confirmed at 115 V.

Comment: Well, you may be getting your money's worth even if you lose one...